# Getting a Linux terminal output of a CLI tool and displaying in Web page

Tags: html, linux, python-3.x, web, terminal

I am trying to create a web application using python which has a HTML form and the form data is used as a command line input to start an application. I know how to initiate the CLI tool from web app, but want a way to get the output of the CLI tool from Linux terminal real time and show it in the web application.

The CLI tool will run for a day and the terminal output will change in real time. Is there a way to display the changing Linux terminal output in to the web application. Information about any web terminal or way to get and store the real-time screen output of a linux application will be helpful.

When ever the screen O/P of the application running in linux changes then the web application should also be updated with the change.

Any python lib or tools will be useful and easy to Integrate?

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution I would do (without any libraries or stuff):

1. invoke your CLI program and set it up to continuously output to a file on the server. Make sure you know the file name.
2. use Ajax calls to fetch the output to the client. OR (if you are in for hard stuff) use a webSocket to output to the client.